# Insert values if it doesn't exist mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name fruits.

```
FRUITS     ITEMS
______
APPLE        6
ORANGE       7
GRAPES       4
```

What is the sql query if I don't want to have a duplicate values in fruits. Example if I want to add another values whichs is APPLE 5 and it should not be added

Comment: make the `FRUTS` field `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Make the FRUITS Field UNIQUE.
and then you may use query like this  
""
Insert into table_name (fruits,item) values ('Apple',' 5')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  items = '5';""

Answer (score 0):

You should set column fruits to `unique`. In this way if you try to add duplicate fruits sql won't let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a unique column, otherwise you can use this query:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(FRUITS, ITEMS) VALUES('APPLE','5')
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT FRUITS
    FROM tablename
    WHERE FRUITS = 'APPLE')
```